# Kou model — solving PIDE for European and American options in Python

Tags: option-pricing, jump-diffusion, jump, pde

Toivanen proposed$^\color{magenta}{\star}$ a method to solve the partial integro-differential equation (PIDE) with a numerical scheme based on [Crank-Nicolson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method). In particular, he proposed an algorithm to estimate quickly the integral, saving a significant amount of time.

I have tried to implement it in Python (and NumPy) but I found out that the price of an European option at-the-money deviates from the price in the original  paper ($3.7755$ versus $3.97347$). Option features are detailed in my code below and the double exponential distribution as well.

```python
from IPython.display import display
import sympy
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def display_matrix(m):
    display(sympy.Matrix(m))

#Option characteristics
S0 = 100.; r = 0.05; K = 100.; Sigma = 0.15; T = 0.25

#Diffusion parameters
Lambda = .1; Alpha1 = 3.0465; Alpha2 = 3.0775; p = 0.3445; q = 1. - p
Zeta = p * Alpha1 /(Alpha1 - 1.) + q * Alpha2 /(Alpha2 + 1.) - 1.

#Grid Parameters
M = 5000 ; N = 400; Beta = 10.3; a = 4.; Gamma = 0.45

#Vector integral term
AMinus = np.zeros(M+1)
APlus  = np.zeros(M+1)  

# Spatial Grid
index_x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=M, num=M+1)
gridX = K * (1 + np.sinh(Beta *(index_x/M - Gamma))/np.sinh(Beta*Gamma))
gridDelta =  gridX[1:] - gridX[:-1]

#Time Grid
def fillTimeGrid(k):
    if k < N: 
        return T * (a**(-k/(N+2.))-1.)/(1./a - 1.)              , 0.5
    else:     
        return T * (a**(-(k + N )/(2.*N+4.)) - 1.)/(1./a - 1.)  , 1.

index_t = np.linspace(start=0, stop=N+4, num=N+5)
gridT, Theta = np.vectorize(fillTimeGrid)(index_t)

gridDeltaT = gridT[1:] - gridT[:-1]

def multJ(v: np.ndarray, kprime: int) -> np.ndarray:

    temp1 = 0.
    temp2 = 0.
    # Initialization
    AMinus[0] = q / (1. + Alpha2) * (v0(gridT[kprime]) + Alpha2 * v[1])
    
    for i in range(0,M-2):
        temp1 = q * gridX[i+1]**(-Alpha2) / ((1. + Alpha2) * gridDelta[i]) * (gridX[i+1]**(1. + Alpha2) - (gridX[i+1] + Alpha2 * gridDelta[i]) * gridX[i]  **(Alpha2)) * v[i-1]
        temp2 = q * gridX[i+1]**(-Alpha2) / ((1. + Alpha2) * gridDelta[i]) * (gridX[i  ]**(1. + Alpha2) - (gridX[i]   - Alpha2 * gridDelta[i]) * gridX[i+1]**(Alpha2)) * v[i]

        AMinus[i+1] = (gridX[i] / gridX[i+1])**(Alpha2) * AMinus[i] + temp1 + temp2       

    # Initialization
    temp1 = 0.
    temp2 = 0.
    
    APlus[M]   = 0.
    APlus[M-1] = p * gridX[M-1]**(Alpha1) / ((Alpha1 - 1.) * gridDelta[M-1]) * (gridX[M]**(1. - Alpha1) - (gridX[M] - Alpha1 * gridDelta[M-1]) * gridX[M-1]**(-Alpha1)) * v[M-2]
    
    for i in range(M-1,1,-1):
        temp1 = p * gridX[i-1]**(Alpha1)/((Alpha1 - 1.) * gridDelta[i-1]) * (gridX[i  ]**(1. - Alpha1) - (gridX[i]     - Alpha1 * gridDelta[i-1]) * gridX[i-1]**(-Alpha1)) * v[i-2]
        temp2 = p * gridX[i-1]**(Alpha1)/((Alpha1 - 1.) * gridDelta[i-1]) * (gridX[i-1]**(1. - Alpha1) - (gridX[i-1]   + Alpha1 * gridDelta[i-1]) * gridX[i  ]**(-Alpha1)) * v[i-1]
        APlus[i-1] = (gridX[i-1] / gridX[i])**(Alpha1) * APlus[i] + temp1 + temp2
    
    return -Lambda * (AMinus[1:M] + APlus[1:M]) 

def v0(tau: float) -> float:
   return K * np.exp(-r*(T-tau))

#initialization of the v - Final value
v = np.maximum(0., K - gridX[1:-1])
v_previous = v; g = v

#D Matrix
SigmaE = np.maximum(Sigma * Sigma, (r - Lambda * Zeta) * gridDelta[1:]/gridX[1:-1], -(r - Lambda * Zeta) * gridDelta[:-1]/gridX[1:-1])
DDMinus = gridX[1:-1] * (-SigmaE * gridX[1:-1] + (r - Lambda * Zeta) * gridDelta[1:]) / (gridDelta[:-1] * (gridDelta[1:] + gridDelta[:-1]))
DDPlus  = gridX[1:-1] * (-SigmaE * gridX[1:-1] - (r - Lambda * Zeta) * gridDelta[:-1]) / (gridDelta[1:] * (gridDelta[1:] + gridDelta[:-1]))
DDCenter = r + Lambda - DDMinus - DDPlus

D = np.diag(DDMinus[1:M], -1) + np.diag(DDCenter[0:M-1]) + np.diag(DDPlus[0:M-2], 1)
if M <= 100: display_matrix(D)

for k in range(N+3, -1,- 1):
    # Equation (32), (33) and (34)
    M1 = np.eye(M-1) + Theta[k] * gridDeltaT[k] * D 
    M2 = np.eye(M-1) - (1. - Theta[k]) * gridDeltaT[k] * D 
    M1_inv = np.linalg.inv(M1)
    
    b = np.matmul(M2, v) 
    d = 1.
    v_previous = v
    v1 = v    
    
    #Jv and solve the equation (38) in the paper
    normVectorb = np.linalg.norm(b)
    while(d > 1.0e-10*normVectorb):
        v1 = b - Theta[k] * gridDeltaT[k] * multJ(v_previous, k) 
        v1 = np.matmul(M1_inv, v1)
        d  = np.linalg.norm(Theta[k] * gridDeltaT[k] * multJ(v1, k) -Theta[k] * gridDeltaT[k] * multJ(v_previous, k) )
        v_previous = v1

    #Update Price vector        
    v = v1

oPriceCall = np.interp(S0, gridX[0:M-1], v[0:M-1]) + S0 - K*np.exp(-r*T)
oPricePut  = np.interp(S0, gridX[1:-1], v)
print(f'The call Price with a spot value {S0} at the money is {oPriceCall} while the put price is {oPricePut}.')
```

The help of anyone familiar with this model and its implementation will be much appreciated because I have been looking into this problem for days (and nights). Any reference to any papers or books detailing the implementation will be helpful too.

**EDIT**
Instead of a Crank-Nicolson scheme, I have tried a full implicit scheme. Then, I managed to retrieve the price of the price of the call and put option given in their paper. I am still not sure why. I will keep using this setting for developing the American option pricing in this framework.

Thanks to everyone!

---

<sub>$\color{magenta}{\star}$ Jari Toivanen, [Numerical valuation of European and American options under Kou's jump-diffusion model](https://web.archive.org/web/20170705104243/http://users.jyu.fi/%7Etene/papers/reportB11-06.pdf).</sub>

Comment: Please can we close this question since I answer myself to my question?

Answer (score 1):

The issue I described in my initial question is linked to the integral term. In the paper, this term is multiply by $ \theta \Delta \text{t} $ but this is only the "implicit" part of the Crank-Nicolson. What is missing is the explicit part which should be multiplied by $ ( 1- \theta) \Delta  \text{t} $. It appears that this term is missing in the paper and then in my implementation.

I attached a corrected code below:

````
from IPython.display import display
import sympy
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def display_matrix(m):
    display(sympy.Matrix(m))

#Option characteristics
S0 = 110.; r = 0.05; K = 100.; Sigma = 0.15; T = 0.25

#Diffusion parameters
Lambda = .1; Alpha1 = 3.0465; Alpha2 = 3.0775; p = 0.3445; q = 1. - p
Zeta = p * Alpha1 /(Alpha1 - 1.) + q * Alpha2 /(Alpha2 + 1.) - 1.

#Grid Parameters
M = 1000 ; N = 1000; Beta = 12.3; a = 4.; Gamma = 0.45

#Vector integral term
AMinus = np.zeros(M+1)
APlus  = np.zeros(M+1)  

#Bounday limit
f = np.zeros(M-1)
f[0] = 1.

# Spatial Grid
index_x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=M, num=M+1)
gridX = K * (1 + np.sinh(Beta *(index_x/M - Gamma))/np.sinh(Beta*Gamma))
gridDelta =  gridX[1:] - gridX[:-1]

#Time Grid
def fillTimeGrid(k):
    if k < N: 
        return T * (a**(-k/(N+2.))-1.)/(1./a - 1.)              , 0.5
    else:     
        return T * (a**(-(k + N )/(2.*N+4.)) - 1.)/(1./a - 1.)  , 1.

index_t = np.linspace(start=0, stop=N+4, num=N+5)
gridT, Theta = np.vectorize(fillTimeGrid)(index_t)
gridDeltaT = gridT[1:] - gridT[:-1]

def multJ(v: np.ndarray, kprime: int) -> np.ndarray:

    #Vector integral term
    AMinus = np.zeros(M+1)
    APlus  = np.zeros(M+1)

    # Initialization
    AMinus[0] = q / (1. + Alpha2) * (v0(kprime)+ Alpha2 * v[0])
    
    for i in range(0,M-1):
        temp1 = (gridX[i+1]**(1. + Alpha2) - (gridX[i+1] + Alpha2 * gridDelta[i]) * gridX[i]  **(Alpha2)) * v[i-1]
        temp2 = (gridX[i  ]**(1. + Alpha2) - (gridX[i]   - Alpha2 * gridDelta[i]) * gridX[i+1]**(Alpha2)) * v[i]
        AMinus[i+1] = (gridX[i] / gridX[i+1])**(Alpha2) * AMinus[i] + q * gridX[i+1]**(-Alpha2) / ((1. + Alpha2) * gridDelta[i]) * (temp1 + temp2)       
    
    APlus[M]   = 0.
    APlus[M-1] = p * gridX[M-1]**(Alpha1) / ((Alpha1 - 1.) * gridDelta[M-1]) * (gridX[M]**(1. - Alpha1) - (gridX[M] - Alpha1 * gridDelta[M-1]) * gridX[M-1]**(-Alpha1)) * v[M-2]
    
    for i in range(M-1,1,-1):
        temp1 = (gridX[i  ]**(1. - Alpha1) - (gridX[i]     - Alpha1 * gridDelta[i-1]) * gridX[i-1]**(-Alpha1)) * v[i-2]
        temp2 = (gridX[i-1]**(1. - Alpha1) - (gridX[i-1]   + Alpha1 * gridDelta[i-1]) * gridX[i  ]**(-Alpha1)) * v[i-1]
        APlus[i-1] = (gridX[i-1] / gridX[i])**(Alpha1) * APlus[i] + p * gridX[i-1]**(Alpha1)/((Alpha1 - 1.) * gridDelta[i-1]) * (temp1 + temp2)
    
    return -Lambda * (AMinus[1:M] + APlus[1:M]) 

def v0(k) -> float:
   return np.maximum(0., K * np.exp(-r*(T-gridT[k]))  )

#initialization of the v - Final value
v = np.maximum(0., K - gridX[1:-1])
v_previous = v; g = v
if M <= 100: display_matrix([gridX[1:-1].round(4), v.round(4)])

#D Matrix
SigmaE = np.maximum(Sigma * Sigma, (r - Lambda * Zeta) * gridDelta[1:]/gridX[1:-1], -(r - Lambda * Zeta) * gridDelta[:-1]/gridX[1:-1])
#SigmaE = Sigma * Sigma
DDMinus = gridX[1:-1] * (-SigmaE * gridX[1:-1] + (r - Lambda * Zeta) * gridDelta[1:]) / (gridDelta[:-1] * (gridDelta[1:] + gridDelta[:-1]))
DDPlus  = gridX[1:-1] * (-SigmaE * gridX[1:-1] - (r - Lambda * Zeta) * gridDelta[:-1]) / (gridDelta[1:] * (gridDelta[1:] + gridDelta[:-1]))
DDCenter = r + Lambda - DDMinus - DDPlus

D = np.diag(DDMinus[1:M], -1) + np.diag(DDCenter[0:M-1]) + np.diag(DDPlus[0:M-2], 1)
if abs(DDMinus[0]) > 0:print(f'DD is not null {DDMinus[0], 4}')
if M <= 100: display_matrix(D.round(4))

for k in range(N+3, -1,- 1):
    # Equation (32), (33) and (34)
    M1 = np.eye(M-1) + Theta[k] * gridDeltaT[k] * D 
    M2 = np.eye(M-1) - (1. - Theta[k]) * gridDeltaT[k] * D 
    M1_inv = np.linalg.inv(M1)

    b = np.matmul(M2, v) 

    #Boundary limit
    b = b - DDMinus[0] * gridDeltaT[k] * (Theta[k] * v0(k) + (1. - Theta[k]) * v0(k+1)) * f

    d = 1.
    v_previous = v
    v1 = v    
    
    #Jv and solve the equation (38) in the paper
    normVectorb = np.linalg.norm(b)
    while(d > 1.0e-10*normVectorb):


        v1 = b - gridDeltaT[k] * (Theta[k] * multJ(v_previous, k) + (1. - Theta[k]) * multJ(v, k+1))
        v1 = np.matmul(M1_inv, v1)
        d  = np.linalg.norm(v1 - v_previous)
        v_previous = v1

    #Update Price vector        
    v = v1

    print(k," ", gridDeltaT[k], " ", gridT[k],",", np.interp(S0, gridX[0:M-1], v[0:M-1]) + S0 - K*np.exp(-r*(T-gridT[k]))," ", DDMinus[0])

oPriceCall = np.interp(S0, gridX[1:-1], v) + S0 - K * np.exp(-r*T)
oPricePut  = np.interp(S0, gridX[1:-1], v)
print(f'The call Price with a spot value {S0} at the money is {oPriceCall} while the put price is {oPricePut}.')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(gridX[0:M-2], v[0:M-2], s=0.5)
ax.scatter(gridX[0:M-2], g[0:M-2], s=0.5)
plt.show()


```
````